# Ubuntu live USB stuck on loading screen

Tags: boot, 20.04, usb

I have a Ryzen 5800u HP laptop without a graphics card. I made an Ubuntu 20.04 live USB. I get to the grub thing and then select Ubuntu. It then performs some kind of file integrity check, which passes without errors.
Then nothing happens. I have been staring at a black screen with the Ubuntu logo, the HP logo and a spinning loading circle. For 5 min.

Comment: Oh yeah it says failed to load rescue.target.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I face the exact same problem every time whenever I do a fresh ubuntu install in my **HP laptop**.

**This can be simply resolved by plugging your usb out for some seconds(1-3 seconds) during the ubuntu is loading with the hp logo and then push back into the laptop.**

This way the ubuntu will start loading files. This works because due to some reason the boot files are not loaded while installation or creating a live ubuntu. So doing this in out process helps to fetch the file that was needed for the process. Enjoy!!